# Keep HISTORY_IGNORE patterns out of the internal history buffer

Tags: zsh

I've set up HISTORY_IGNORE with some patterns, but the patterns are still captured in zsh's internal command buffer. If I run history, I can see the patterned command was not captured in the history file, but I want to clear it from my internal buffer too.

```
 HISTORY_IGNORE
          If set, is treated as a pattern at the time history files are written.  Any potential history entry that matches the  pattern
          is  skipped.   For example, if the value is `fc *' then commands that invoke the interactive history editor are never written
          to the history file.

          Note that HISTORY_IGNORE defines a single pattern: to specify alternatives use the `(first|second|...)' syntax.

          Compare the HIST_NO_STORE option or the zshaddhistory hook, either of which would prevent such commands from being  added  to
          the  interactive  history  at all.  If you wish to use HISTORY_IGNORE to stop history being added in the first place, you can
          define the following hook:

                 zshaddhistory() {
                   emulate -L zsh
                   ## uncomment if HISTORY_IGNORE
                   ## should use EXTENDED_GLOB syntax
                   # setopt extendedglob
                   [[ $1 != ${~HISTORY_IGNORE} ]]
                 }
```

How can I clear the offending command from my internal buffer as soon as it is typed? Internal buffer as in, the buffer I scroll through with the arrow keys.
Here is what I have so far:

```
HISTSIZE=2000
HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
SAVEHIST=$HISTSIZE
setopt hist_ignore_all_dups
setopt hist_ignore_space
setopt extendedglob
HISTORY_IGNORE='(git reset*|reboot|shutdown|exit|cd ..|cd ~|..|~)'

zshaddhistory() {
  emulate -L zsh
  [[ $1 != ${~HISTORY_IGNORE} ]]
}
```

Comment: You already have `setopt hist_ignore_space` so as a workaround you could add a space in front of commands that you don't want to store in the current session, or setup a aliases like `alias shutdown=' shutdown'` to automate it a bit more (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539771 for an example).

Comment: That method may work for single commands, but will not apply to space separated options like `git reset --hard`. e.g I cant `alias git reset --hard=' git reset --hard'`

Comment: That's true, hence 'workaround' :) as a further workaround you could of course set `alias gitresethard=' git reset --hard'`. Or get used to prepending the space manually when you type the commands.

Comment: I was experimenting and found if I bitwise OR in zshaddhistory, `[[ $1 != ${~HISTORY_IGNORE} ]] | fc -R $HISTFILE` I can activate something when offending patterns are matched, perhaps reload history with `fc -R $HISTFILE`, though this doesn't quite work in practice.

Comment: Maybe I could change the command buffer to add a space before, e.g. `" $1"`, though Im not sure how to set the command buffer directly.

Comment: the `hist_ignore_space` option only applies to your history file, not the internal buffer, its still saved there which is what I am trying to prevent. so that wont work...

Comment: Actually it _does_ work for the internal buffer (I just tried), but not for the most recent command, which is always kept. If you type another command after it, or just a space followed by enter, then the previous command will not show when pressing the up key (see the answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48305/how-can-i-run-a-command-in-zsh-without-pushing-it-onto-the-current-sessions-his).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id like to simulate the enter key without external packages, but zsh doesnt have a function at the moment to simulate keystrokes. Thats okay. With this config, restricted patterns will be cleared once I hit the enter key after the restricted pattern. Good enough. Atleast I dont have to accidentally wipe 30+ minutes of work in git after scrolling too far and stumbling across a previous `git reset --hard`.

(edited)

```
HISTSIZE=2000
HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
SAVEHIST=$HISTSIZE
setopt hist_ignore_all_dups
setopt hist_ignore_space
setopt extendedglob

HISTORY_IGNORE='(git reset*|reboot|shutdown|exit|cd ..|cd ~|..|~)'

zshaddhistory() 
{
  emulate -L zsh
  [[ $1 != ${~HISTORY_IGNORE} ]]
}
```

Comment: `fc -R $HISTFILE` above is actually entirely unnecessary, I guess when I was testing this I was caught off guard because zsh will always save the last run command no matter if its in the HISTORY_IGNORE. so `[[ $1 != ${~HISTORY_IGNORE} ]]` is enough. after a return carriage, the bad pattern is wiped from the internal buffer.